Is there a way to make production creation required/mandatory when user is creating opportunity?
When user is creating a new opportunity can we make it mandatory to add a new product. I know about "Opportunity Settings" on setup that we can use to prompt "add products to Opportunities" modal/pop-up but is there any way to make it mandatory or any other way to make product creation mandatory when user is creating opportunity.
I tried "Opportunity Settings" on the setup page but It only prompt "add product" option after the opportunity is created. I want it to be mandatory for user to create a product when user creates opportunity.
